# Unable to debug dockerize Angular app in VS Code - Cannot connect to the target: socket hang up

Tags: angular, docker, visual-studio-code, angular-cli

I am trying to debug an Angular app which is running inside a container but I am getting the following error:

[image: Ca]

**AppData\Local\Temp\vscode-chrome-debug.txt:**

```
[11:27:35.501 UTC] OS: win32 x64
[11:27:35.501 UTC] Adapter node: v10.11.0 x64
[11:27:35.501 UTC] vscode-chrome-debug-core: 6.7.53
[11:27:35.501 UTC] debugger-for-chrome: 4.11.7
[11:27:35.501 UTC] From client: initialize({"clientID":"vscode","clientName":"Visual Studio Code","adapterID":"chrome","pathFormat":"path","linesStartAt1":true,"columnsStartAt1":true,"supportsVariableType":true,"supportsVariablePaging":true,"supportsRunInTerminalRequest":true,"locale":"en-us"})
[11:27:35.501 UTC] To client: {"seq":0,"type":"response","request_seq":1,"command":"initialize","success":true,"body":{"exceptionBreakpointFilters":[{"label":"All Exceptions","filter":"all","default":false},{"label":"Uncaught Exceptions","filter":"uncaught","default":false}],"supportsConfigurationDoneRequest":true,"supportsSetVariable":true,"supportsConditionalBreakpoints":true,"supportsCompletionsRequest":true,"supportsHitConditionalBreakpoints":true,"supportsRestartFrame":true,"supportsExceptionInfoRequest":true,"supportsDelayedStackTraceLoading":true,"supportsValueFormattingOptions":true,"supportsEvaluateForHovers":true,"supportsLoadedSourcesRequest":true,"supportsRestartRequest":true,"supportsSetExpression":true,"supportsLogPoints":true}}
[11:27:35.501 UTC] To client: {"seq":0,"type":"event","event":"output","body":{"category":"telemetry","output":"ClientRequest/initialize","data":{"Versions.DebugAdapterCore":"6.7.53","Versions.DebugAdapter":"4.11.7","successful":"true","timeTakenInMilliseconds":"5.823501","requestType":"request"}}}
[11:27:35.501 UTC] From client: launch({"type":"chrome","request":"launch","name":"UI Launch (Docker)","url":"http://localhost:4200","webRoot":"D:\\Saurabh\\Projects\\vscode-workflow/ng-app","sourceMapPathOverrides":{"webpack:/*":"${webRoot}/*","/./*":"${webRoot}/*","/src/*":"${webRoot}/*","/*":"*","/./~/*":"${webRoot}/node_modules/*"},"trace":true,"runtimeArgs":["--remote-debugging-port=9222"],"__sessionId":"079a3ab7-942d-4dfe-807b-0be98d6fca6f"})
[11:27:35.501 UTC] To client: {"seq":0,"type":"event","event":"output","body":{"category":"telemetry","output":"debugStarted","data":{"Versions.DebugAdapterCore":"6.7.53","Versions.DebugAdapter":"4.11.7","request":"launch","args":["type","request","name","url","webRoot","sourceMapPathOverrides","trace","runtimeArgs","__sessionId","breakOnLoadStrategy","pathMapping","sourceMaps","skipFileRegExps","targetFilter","smartStep","showAsyncStacks"]}}}
[11:27:35.501 UTC] Getting browser and debug protocol version via http://127.0.0.1:9222/json/version
[11:27:35.501 UTC] Discovering targets via http://127.0.0.1:9222/json/list
[11:27:35.506 UTC] HTTP GET failed: Error: socket hang up
[11:27:35.507 UTC] Discovering targets via http://127.0.0.1:9222/json
[11:27:35.508 UTC] HTTP GET failed: Error: socket hang up
[11:27:35.508 UTC] There was an error connecting to http://127.0.0.1:9222/json/version : socket hang up
[11:27:35.521 UTC] HTTP GET failed: Error: socket hang up
[11:27:35.674 UTC] [chromeSpawnHelper] spawn('C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe', ["--remote-debugging-port=9222","--no-first-run","--no-default-browser-check","--remote-debugging-port=9222","--user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\spala\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\vscode-chrome-debug-userdatadir_9222","about:blank"])
```

Here is the [source code](https://github.com/SaurabhLpRocks/vscode-workflow).

**Folder Structure:**

[image]

**./ng-app/angular.json:**

```
"serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "ng-app:build",
            "open": true,
            "host": "0.0.0.0",
            "port": 80
          }
        }
```

**./ng-app/.docker/development.dockerfile:**

```
FROM node:10.15.1-alpine
LABEL author="Saurabh Palatkar"
RUN mkdir /usr/share/app
WORKDIR /usr/share/app
COPY package.json package.json
RUN npm i -g @angular/cli@8.0.3
COPY package-lock.json package-lock.json
RUN npm i
COPY . .
ENV PATH /node_modules/.bin:$PATH
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 9222
CMD ["sh", "-c", "ng serve --host=0.0.0.0 --watch --poll=2000"]
```

**./ng-app/docker-compose.development.yml:**
version: "3.4"

```
services:
  ng-app-service:
    image: ng.app.dev.image
    container_name: ng.app.dev.container
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: .docker/development.dockerfile
    environment:
      NODE_ENV: development
    volumes:
      - "./:/usr/share/app"
      - /app/node_modules/
    ports:
      - 4200:80
      - 9222:9222
    command:
      [
        "sh",
        "-c",
        "npm start --host=0.0.0.0 --watch --poll=2000 --inspect=9222 --remote-debugging-port=9222 --nolazy",
      ]
```

**./.vscode/launch.json:**

```
{
      "type": "chrome",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "UI Launch (Docker)",
      "url": "http://localhost:4200",
      "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/ng-app",
      "sourceMapPathOverrides": {
        "webpack:/*": "${webRoot}/*",
        "/./*": "${webRoot}/*",
        "/src/*": "${webRoot}/*",
        "/*": "*",
        "/./~/*": "${webRoot}/node_modules/*"
      },
      "trace": true,
      "runtimeArgs": ["--remote-debugging-port=9222"]
    }
```

**./.vscode/tasks.json:**

```
{
      "label": "serve ui dev docker",
      "type": "npm",
      "script": "serve-ui-dev-docker",
      "isBackground": true,
      "presentation": {
        "focus": true,
        "panel": "dedicated"
      },
      "group": {
        "kind": "build",
        "isDefault": true
      },
      "problemMatcher": {
        "owner": "typescript",
        "source": "ts",
        "applyTo": "closedDocuments",
        "fileLocation": ["relative", "${cwd}"],
        "pattern": "$tsc",
        "background": {
          "activeOnStart": true,
          "beginsPattern": {
            "regexp": "(.*?)"
          },
          "endsPattern": {
            "regexp": "Compiled |Failed to compile."
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

**./package.json:**

```
"scripts": {
    "serve-ui-dev-docker": "cd ng-app && docker-compose -f docker-compose.development.yml up --build"
  },
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried to replicate your issue but I noticed earlier that the problems might be in the CMD in your dockerfile and the `command` block in your docker-compose.yml.

The CMD uses the exec format and it should read:

```
CMD ["ng", "serve", "--host=0.0.0.0", "--watch", "--poll=2000"]
```

or

```
CMD ng serve --host=0.0.0.0 --watch --poll=2000
```

NOTE: I removed the `sh -c` since it's not needed.

src: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd

---

In the docker-compose there's the same problem:

```
command: [ "npm", "start", "--host=0.0.0.0", "--watch", "--poll=2000", "--inspect=9222", "--remote-debugging-port=9222", "--nolazy" ]
```

src: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#command

Try these changes and check if the docker image can start from the command line first.

---

The second problem I'm seeing is that you don't need to define the node inspect process to debug the angular application. The code will be debugged in  chrome not by the `ng serve` process. I'd suggest to remove the 9222 port mapping from the docker-compose file and the `"runtimeArgs": ["--remote-debugging-port=9222"]` from the launch.json for the `UI Launch (Docker)`

Comment: Still, have the same issue. Can you check this source code? https://github.com/SaurabhLpRocks/vscode-workflow

Comment: Did the docker related changes in the first part of your answer, and tried to run the docker from the command line and it worked. But after making changes in the second part of the answer, I am getting a slightly new error (Chrome debug): "Cannot connect to runtime process, timeout after 10000 ms - (reason: Cannot connect to the target: connect ECONNREFUSED 12.0.0.1:9222)."

Comment: I was getting these kind of errors as well. The problem in my case was that I had to remove the older docker containers and rebuild the image.

Comment: Worked after recreating container.